# upload PDF to S3 with NodeJS gives me a 80 Bytes file

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a recently created PDF to S3:

Here is my code:

```
ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, './views/', "global.ejs"), {
        operatioName: recap.operation.label,
        operationId: recap.operation.name,
        date: recap.date,
        date_ini: moment(recap.date_ini, "DDMMYYYY").locale('fr').format("DD MMMM"),
        date_end: moment(recap.date_end, "DDMMYYYY").locale('fr').format("DD MMMM YYYY"),
        autoConsoTotal: autoConsoTotal,
        consoTotal: consoTotal,
        prodTotal: prodTotal,
        surplusTotal: surplusTotal,
        yearAndMonthFolder: yearAndMonthFolder,

    }, (err, data) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            // res.render('global.ejs', {
            //     operatioName: operationLabel,
            //     operationId: operation,
            //     month: recapMonth,
            //     date: RECAP_DATE,
            //     autoConsoTotal: autoConsoTotal,
            //     consoTotal: consoTotal,
            //     prodTotal: prodTotal,
            //     surplusTotal: surplusTotal,
            // });
            let options = {
                filename: 'public/pdf/' + recap.operation.name + "/" + yearAndMonthFolder + '-BilanGlobal.pdf',
                format: 'A4',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                type: "pdf",
                paginationOffset: 1,
                "renderDelay": 1000,
                "base": "/home/julien/Code/customer_recap.mine/public/images/" + recap.operation.name + "/" + yearAndMonthFolder + "/",
            };

            pdf.create(data, options).toFile(function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(options);
                    // Upload to S3
                    var params = {
                        Key: recap.operation.name + "/reports/" + yearAndMonthFolder + "-BilanGlobal.pdf",
                        Body: data['filename'],
                        Bucket: 'sunchain',
                        ContentType: 'application/pdf'
                    }

                    s3.putObject(params, function (err, response) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                        } else {
                            console.error(response);
                        }
                    });
                }

            });


        }
    });
```

I downloaded my file, renamed it to .txt, and I could check that instead of having PDF data, it only has the path inside:

```
/home/julien/Code/customer_recap/public/pdf/ACC000000/09012020_08022020-BilanGlobal.pdf
```

How should I do ? I have seen some tutos use `toStream` instead of `toFile` but I also want it to be generated in local, so toFile is good for me.

Comment: Why are you sending `data['filename']` as the body of the S3 object? Wouldn't that just be the PDF's filename?

Comment: I give it the path of the file to upload. but it upload the name only

Comment: That's because the API is expecting the body of the file (its contents) not the filename. If you read the API docs, you'll see that `Body` can be one of Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream. For a stream, use something like `fs.createReadStream(data['filename'])`.

Comment: I will try monday! Week end time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the API documentation for [putObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property), you'll see that `Body` can be one of Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream. Specifically, it is the *content* of the file rather than the *name* of the file.

For a stream, use `Body: fs.createReadStream(data['filename'])`